# Slow mysql query execution across local network

Tags: mysql, networking

I have a mysql database set up on a mac mini server on a local network.  When I query the database from the server as the root user, everything behaves well.  However, I am having serious problems when I log into mysql from another machine on the local network I perform those same queries.

For example, the table `items` has 1,831,218 rows and two columns, `item` and `total` (not indexed). When I perform the following query is is very quick as expected:

```
mysql> select * from items limit 10;
+------+-----------+
| item | total     |
+------+-----------+
| a    | 577846916 |
| b    | 489378579 |
| c    | 485798873 |
| d    | 476865689 |
| e    | 425954264 |
| f    | 399431640 |
| g    | 375218023 |
| h    | 325892006 |
| i    | 169948795 |
| j    | 116927132 |
+------+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now by logging in remotely from another machine on the network:`>mysql --host=192.168.2.2 -u newuser -p`, where `newuser` has select privileges on the database, I perform the same query and get wildly different execution times.

```
mysql> select * from items limit 10;
+------+-----------+
| item | total     |
+------+-----------+
| a    | 577846916 |
| b    | 489378579 |
| c    | 485798873 |
| d    | 476865689 |
| e    | 425954264 |
| f    | 399431640 |
| g    | 375218023 |
| h    | 325892006 |
| i    | 169948795 |
| j    | 116927132 |
+------+-----------+
10 rows in set (7 min 3.10 sec)
```

This is an exceptionally bad example that doesn't happen all the time, but in general queries are much slower (usually 10-100 times slower (or more) than on the server itself). For this much of a slow down it doesn't seem likely that the bottleneck has to do with latency in the network, but rather some configuration issue that is causing mysql to not communicate well with between the server and the various nodes.

Aside from verifying that both machines are running he same version of mysql: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for osx10.7 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`, I am not sure what other settings to verify and what else to do to try to fix this problem.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas, thank you.

Comment: With the way you are running this (using mysql with the --host option from the local host), if the mysql engine is actually running on the local host, but the data is on the remote host.  So, the slow query times that you are seeing when you run it this way are a result of all 1,831,218 of the records in the table having to be transferred from the remote host through the network, to the remote host, where they are processed.  Instead of doing it this way, can you SSH from the local host to the remote host, then run mysql (on the remote host), and see if you get much quicker query times?

Comment: First of all, table does not need to be copied to the node to execute a query, in general the only data that is being sent across the network is the result of a query. Second, SSHing into the server does speed up query execution.  While this solves my problem as stated (by speeding up query execution), this is not the most desirable solution. The reason is that there doesn't seem to be the same work around for the various mysql connectors (such as the MySQldb module in python). I really need to be able to use the standard connections (with the --host option) in mysql to use these libraries.